# Universal properties of $\mathbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra, universal-property

> What is the universal property of ℤ as a group? What is the universal property of ℤ as a ring? Explain why the answers
>   to each of these questions are different.

I have been able to show that this is an initial object in Rings. But haven't shown what the property for groups is.

Comment: No I mean, there is a universal property for Z with respect to groups. I don't know what that is.

Comment: Perhaps the universal property as a free group $F_1=\Bbb Z$?

Comment: Right, but how do I notate that. The construction seems hard to me.

Comment: The question isn’t about a construction, it’s about a universal property. So you wan to write out the universal property for the free group in one generator, not construct the free group.

Comment: Thanks for the help! If you'd post this with a bit more detail as an answer id be happy to upvote and accept! Just one clarification, why are they different.

Comment: Who are you talking to, and what things are you refering to when you say “how are they different”?

Comment: Why are the universal properties as a ring and group different.

Comment: Because groups and rings are different?

Comment: Yeah so groups and rings are different obviously. But what is the particular difference that changes the universal property.

Answer (score 9):

I'd be happy to discuss this in person either during or after your oral exam. Come find me in my office.

Comment: ... what an interesting interchange ...